# How to Update a record in spring boot and mysql

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I am a newbie to spring boot.I have created a crud operation and the insert operation is working properly. I have a challenge on the update operation , the program is giving an error on the web page

**Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.Wed Jul 22 20:39:03 CAT 2020 There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400)**

and the following error from the console

**Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "saveEmployee"]**

how can I solve the problem?

my code is below

Controller Class

````
```
package com.zimprogrammer.springboot.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import com.zimprogrammer.springboot.model.Employee;
import com.zimprogrammer.springboot.service.EmployeeService;

@Controller 
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String vieHomePage(Model model) {
    
        // this shows a list of employees
        model.addAttribute("listEmployees", employeeService.getAllEmployees());
        return "index";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/showEmployeeForm")
    public String showEmployeeForm(Model model){
        
        //request for the form to enter the data 
        Employee employee =new Employee();
        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        return "new_employee";
    
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/saveEmployee")
    public String saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee) {
        //save data to the database
        
        employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/showFormForUpdate/{id}")
    public String showFormForUpdate(@PathVariable( value="id") long id, Model model) {
        //get the employee from the service
        
        Employee employee =employeeService.getEmployeeById(id);
        
        // set the employee to pre-populate the form
        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        
        return "update_employee";
        
    }
}```

Employee Service Interface
```package com.zimprogrammer.springboot.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.zimprogrammer.springboot.model.Employee;

public interface EmployeeService {
    List<Employee> getAllEmployees();

    void saveEmployee(Employee employee);
    Employee getEmployeeById(long id);
}
```
Employee Service Class 
```
package com.zimprogrammer.springboot.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


import com.zimprogrammer.springboot.model.Employee;
import com.zimprogrammer.springboot.repository.EmployeeRepository;

@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService{

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    
    @Override
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        return employeeRepository.findAll();
    
    }
    
    @Override
    public void saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }

    @Override
    public Employee getEmployeeById(long id) {
        Optional<Employee> optional=employeeRepository.findById(id);
        Employee employee=null;
        
        if(optional.isPresent()) {
            employee=optional.get();
        }else {
            throw new RuntimeException("User not found for id::" + id);
        }
        return employee;
    }
}
```
````

Employee Repository Interface
```
package com.zimprogrammer.springboot.repository;

````
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.zimprogrammer.springboot.model.Employee;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>{

}
```
Update Form : Thymeleaf and bootstrap
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Employee Management System</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="width:40%; height:40%;">
        <h1>Employee Management system</h1>
        <hr>
        <h2>Update Employee</h2>

        <form action="#" th:action="@{saveEmployee}" th:object="${employee}"
            method="POST">
            
            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" />
            
            <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}"
            class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
            <input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}"
                 class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
            <input type="text" th:field="*{email}"
                class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2">Update
                Employee</button>

        </form>
        <hr>
        
        <a th:href = "@{/}"> Back to Employee List</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Can you also post you entity class?

From the error it is telling that the required type is long but it is getting it as string? It may be possible that you have mentioned your id as string instead of long.

Also try to add th:action="@{/saveEmployee}" to be exact as that of your /saveEmployee endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Add "/" in form th:action, like so -> th:action="@{/saveEmployee}"
Also check your crud repository, insted of `long` use `Long`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem

I added a / to make `th:action="@{/saveEmployee}"` and changed `long` to `Long`  in my controller Class in the following request

```
@GetMapping("/showFormForUpdate/{id}")
    public String showFormForUpdate(@PathVariable( value="id") Long id, Model model) {
        //get the employee from the service
        
        Employee employee =employeeService.getEmployeeById(id);
        
        // set the employee to pre-populate the form
        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        
        return "update_employee";
        
    }
```

and this solved the problem